# How to Pass A Generics Type Name IN Java (Android)

Tags: java, android

How to pass a listItemType as an argument and use it in class:

Does Java has the feature?

for example:

```
private ArrayList<mListItemType> mList;
private mEntityType entiry;
private ? mListItemType;

public void setListItemType(? listItemType){
    mListItemType= listItemType
}

public void setEntityType(? entiryType){
    mEntityType= entiryType
}

public void foobar(){

    mList = new ArrayList<mListItemType>();

    entiry = new mEntityType();

    entiry.firstName = "Tom";

}
```

Comment: If you're using Android, some of the newer features of Java might not be supported. You need to check your version and the compatability

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [bounding](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/generics/bounded.html):

```
public <T extends mListItemType> void setEntityType(T entiryType){
```